# MAMP Server is not refreshing

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, wamp, mamp

I've been having this problem the second I downloaded MAMP. I get to programming (AJAX, AngularJS) and it works perfectly most of the time. However, when I start making new files in the folder that is in MAMP's attention, my other files stop updating changes once I try and refresh the page to view changes. Any advice/help? I have already tried disabling cache in Chrome DevTools but it just keeps happening. >:l